# Basic authentication with ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider

Tags: asp.net, iis, active-directory, basic-authentication

I'm trying to get users in the local domain authenticated from ActiveDirectory by iis/asp.net application hosted on a non-domain host.

This is the set up

- local domain = `MYDOMAIN`
- iis host = `10.10.1.1` (not in `MYDOMAIN`)
- ActiveDirectory LDAP connection string =  `LDAP://10.20.1.1/DC=MYDOMAIN,DC=local`

**web.config**

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://10.20.1.1/DC=MYDOMAIN,DC=local" />
</connectionStrings>

...

<authorization>
  <allow users="*"/>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
<membership defaultProvider="ADMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add
       name="ADMembershipProvider"
       type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
       connectionStringName="ADConnectionString"
       connectionUsername="MYDOMAIN\Administrator"
       connectionPassword="password"
       />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

**iis settings**

- Basic Authentication enabled
- All other Authentication methods disabled

But with this set up users are not authenticated when credentials entered on the browser auth prompt (user name entered as `MYDOMAIN\user` - no change without the `MYDOMAIN\` part). I don't see iis even connecting to the AD server (`10.20.1.1`)

What am I doing wrong and how can I debug an issue like this?

Answer (score 1):

Basic Authentication in IIS has no knowledge of Membership Providers in ASP.NET. If you want to do that, then you need to write a custom basic authentication module that uses the Mebership APIs (ValidateUser, RoleProvider and such). Luckily it is extremely easy to do that, and we wrote a sample several years ago on how to do that, see this for the end to end code and configuration of it (do note that the call to membership is commented out in the sample, but you can just uncomment the line) :

http://www.iis.net/learn/develop/runtime-extensibility/developing-a-module-using-net

Comment: Thanks. So are you suggesting that AD authentication by an IIS host which is not in the AD domain can be done only with a custom authentication module? ie. it can't be done with web.config configuration? I thought it's possible based on http://serverfault.com/questions/48526/non-domain-iis-server-authenticate-on-domain

Comment: that is correct, the post you linked to is not using any IIS configuration, it is using ASP.NET Membership providers and likely using Forms Authentication, not Basic Authentication. You could make it work if you are using Forms Authentication in web.config, however your question was about Basic Authentication and that can only be done with a custom basic authentication module. I wonder if your question is wrongly stated and you actually want Forms Authentication?

Comment: I don't want add Forms Auth (basically to avoid adding extra code but configuration). That post seems to suggest he was able to get Basic Auth working with AD (first para of answer) and hence my question as it didn't work me. I take yours as an authoritative answer from Microsoft ;)